# How do I limit the amount of page cache on a system?

Tags: linux, performance, filesystems

I am running HPC workloads and my systems have half a TB of RAM.  I need to prevent the kernel from taking up too much page cache because when it flushes data, it is flushing data so fast that my drives are locking up.

How do I cap the amount of page cache that the kernel will use?

I tried everything I found on google, which are, limiting it in

```
vm.dirty_background_ratio
vm.dirty_background_bytes
vm.dirty_ratio
vm.dirty_bytes
```

and also

```
vm.vfs_cache_preassure
```

Nothing seems to take effect and the kernel keeps increasing  the page cache usage and I need to periodically echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches to workaround this

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [tuning page cache](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Tuning_and_Optimizing_Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux_for_Oracle_9i_and_10g_Databases/sect-Oracle_9i_and_10g_Tuning_Guide-Memory_Usage_and_Page_Cache-Tuning_the_Page_Cache.html). You want to do something like this

```
echo "40" > /proc/sys/vm/pagecache
```

I suggest don't change any thing because LRU/MRU caching algorithms shipped with the kernel are very efficient. Much more than what you can tune.

Comment: sadly enough, it's RHEL only option.

Comment: Not an RHEL feature, but a feature of older kernels.